# XAML Grid Visibility Transition?

Tags: xaml, grid, windows-store-apps, visibility, transition

I have a Grid that has Visibility bound to a property in my viewmodel. This all works fine -- the Grid appears/disappears correctly. My question is, how can I apply a transition so that instead of just instantly disappearing from the screen, the grid content slides into the edge of the UI? When made visible it should slide back out again.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="30,30,0,30"
              Visibility="{Binding IsSearchEnabled, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

...

Comment: You'll just need to fire off a Storyboard animation to accomplish this, generally folks look for effort and then correct what's missing around here instead of just providing code, but if I have time later I'll whip you up an example a bit later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So as a quick example, one way of doing this;

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="TheGrid"
      Margin="30,30,0,30"
      Visibility="{Binding IsSearchEnabled, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- Start the magic -->
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
           <TranslateTransform x:Name="SlideIn" X="750" />
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
      <Grid.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SlideIn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                 <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.25" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TheGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.55" Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                       </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

This will slide it in when it's loaded and even fade in as it goes. You might have to play with the "X" value on SlideIn to get it off the screen to your liking. You could reverse it for the other direction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well okay, it works, but grid loaded event fires only once. since there is no way to dispose the grid element (well actually there is but needs work) is there any other way to achieve same thing?

Comment: @AliDemirci I just had it on that event for the sake of this old example. You can fire it off however you like. What specifically are you having troubles with? Perhaps a separate question is necessary?

Comment: Well I have a page that contains two grids called `LogIn` and `SignUp`. I can be switch between them as much as I want. SignUp grid comes collapsed by default but Grid.Loaded event fires when the page loaded not when visibilty changed. So because of that it animation does not works.

Comment: @AliDemirci So you can set an EventTrigger to watch Visibility and fire off the storyboard with a ControlStoryBoardAction, or you can do it however you want from code with Storyboard.Begin method. Are you just looking for a copy/paste answer? Either way I'm going to suggest you create a new question unique to your current issue. :)

Comment: Okay here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795144/xaml-grid-visibility-transitions @Chris W.