# WP8.1 - How can I show a Flyout at the bottom of the page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm building an app for WP8.1 and I need a custom keyboard to enter some particular character into a TextBox. I decided to use a Flyout to display a User Control with a series of buttons, so that the user will be able to tap on each button to add a new character.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that I can't find a way to display the Flyout in the second half of the page or at the bottom of the page.
This is the method I use to display it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var flyout = new Flyout();
        var tb = new CustomKeyboard();
        flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
        flyout.ShowAt(Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement);
    }
```

This works, but even though I selected the bottom Placement, the Flyout is displayed at the top of my page. I also tried to create a grid with two rows, with another Grid in the second row, and to call the flyout with that inner grid as FrameworkElement, but it still gets displayed at the top of my page, I don't know why.

Am I missing anything? Is there a way to display that flyout at the bottom, or is there another control/class I can use to do that?

Thanks!
Sergio

EDIT: I ended up using a grid and some Storyboards as suggested :)

```
<!--Transitions-->
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="tastieraInDestra">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tastiera" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideIn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         From="750" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="tastieraInSinistra">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tastiera" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideIn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         From="-750" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="tastieraOutDestra">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tastiera" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideIn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         From="0" To="750" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="tastieraOutSinistra">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tastiera" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SlideIn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                         From="0" To="-750" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

I control these Storyboards inside the pivot.SelectionChanged method, and I added everything inside the grid in the main page. The only downside is that now my main page xaml file is getting a bit crowded as I have all my UI in one page, but it works fine :D
Thanks!

Comment: From the docs - "On Windows Phone, a Flyout is shown at the top of the screen by default. You can change the Placement property to FlyoutPlacementMode.Full to make the flyout cover the full screen. The Top, Bottom, Left, and Right values don't have any effect in Windows Phone apps." However, you could fake a flyout of your own pretty easy with a panel and a simple animation storyboard.

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that ahahahah
What you mean by a panel? I could come up with a StoryBoard, but could you give me some samples of your idea for the flyout substitute? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yea, quick example, go check out a relate-able [previous answer like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition) for an example. Throw a TextBlock or whatever in the Grid in that example, give it a background color and place it on top of your other content, place it wherever you want, and fire off the animation with Begin instead of a RoutedEvent, and voila! You have your own flyout to put wherever you want and use however you like, if ya want a more detailed explanation it will have to wait until tomorrow, I'm about to leave for the day :)

Comment: Oh cool I was just getting on here to make sure you got sorted before the end of the day again. Sorry for the delay, buried in work. Anyhow if you got your remedy I guess I'll save the trouble of providing an answer, cheers!

Comment: Yup, I used your answer in the other thread and I edited a couple of things to get the result I wanted, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Oh and PS, if you wanted to clean up some of your XAML clutter, throw those in a resource dictionary and call them as a static resource, would also make them available elsewhere in your app in case you need them again. Either way, cool beans, enjoy :)