# Windows Phone Slide Animation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I need to animate buttons inside a horizontal stackpanel to slide in to the center of the screen.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Button Name="Button1" Content="Button 1" />
                <Button Name="Button2" Content="Button 2" />
                <Button Name="Button3" Content="Button 3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

I know i need to use storyboard for animation. I have not used storyboard a lot hence I am not good with it.

I need to probably use something like the following-

```
<Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" X="500" />
</Button.RenderTransform>
```

And then apply some story board animation to it.

But what will the storyboard animation code be like???

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="translateTransform"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                 From="500" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

the above code would slide one button from one position to another.

But I need a more generic solution, something that would apply to all the buttons/controls inside the stackpanel, so that all the buttons slide to the center of the screen.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take an old answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145) and change the Grid in that example to your StackPanel and you'll have what you want.

Comment: @ChrisW. I saw and tried your example. But its not exactly what I want. In your example the whole grid would slide in. I want the elements inside the grid to slide from left and right to the center og the grid. Or in my case - the StackPanel

Comment: Right, so you just put the animation on your StackPanel and adjust the X setting to suit you.