# Reverse transition in Blend for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, blend

In my winrt app I have two visual states and one transition- from first to second. Is there any way to reverse this transition when change from second to first visual state? I find out how to reverse storyboard animation, but for transitions menu is not active.

Here is xaml of visual states and transition:

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition From="DefaultState"  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.7" To="SelectedState">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="StartTripButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="-1000">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="StartTripButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="-500">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="TripsButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="-1000">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="TripsButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="500">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="PlacesButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="1000">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="PlacesButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="-500">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Calendar">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="1000">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Calendar">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7"
                                Value="500">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.267">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.267" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState" >
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="StartTripButton">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>-1000,-500,1000,500</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="TripsButton">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>-1000,500,1000,-500</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Calendar">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>1000,500,-1000,-500</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="PlacesButton">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>1000,-500,-1000,500</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackButton">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Post your xaml, we'll show you how.

Comment: Whew, I generally wouldn't do all that Margin stuff for that effect personally. However which storyboard / state is the one you're trying to do this to? We can use [VisualTransition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualtransition.aspx) to play the reversed storyboard as it goes `From` one state `To` another.

Comment: What is the proper way to create that kind of effect? Can you provide me a sample of how to use VisualTransition to play the reversed storyboard?

Comment: I would use a RenderTransform with a TranslateTransform like on an example I put up in the past like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145), as for you VisualTransition, what state are you trying to supply the change for?