# Xaml simple storyboard/animation

Tags: xaml, storyboard

I have a Xaml-view containing three buttons and three usercontrols.
I in the code-behind i have buttons that toggles visibility on or off:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button Content="Summer" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Button Content="Winter" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="Autumn" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

            </StackPanel>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <StackPanel Width="600" VerticalAlignment="top" Background="LightGreen">              
                <local:Summer x:Name="Summer" Width="600"></local:Summer>
                <local:Winter x:Name="Winter" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="600"></local:Winter>
                <local:Autumn x:Name="Autumn" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="600"></local:Autumn>             
            </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Autumn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Summer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Winter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Autumn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Summer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Winter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Autumn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Summer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Winter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

I would like to know how to accomplish a simple animation (slide in) by using storyboards or other way. I´ve seen examples online but I have had a hard time making them work in my specifik case.

Comment: Follow my instructions on [this past post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145)

Comment: No prob, let us know if you run into issues