# Sliding view from the bottom in a Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to figure out how to animate a popup coming from the bottom of the screen in a Universal Windows App. I tried searching for all the new UAP controls that are available which might make this easier but I cannot find one.

So I'm resorting to a standard Grid with the bottom RowDefinition with a Height of zero. My UserControl (popup view) is in this last row, and I'm looking for a way to animate the Height of this RowDefinition from 0 to 150.

So my question is this: In a Universal Windows App, is this the only way to do this? Or is there a better and/or easier way?

Comment: You can use an old answer like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145) and just swap the `TranslateTransform` property of `X` for `Y` and change the value to what's required to slide it up from the bottom, and remove the opacity animation if you just want it to slide in. I wouldn't mess with any of that RowDefinition stuff you're talking about. If anything set your Row to Auto and animate the height of the panel and not the row.

Comment: +1 on using Transforms. If you do have to animate the `Height` for some reason, make sure you set the `EnableDependentAnimation` property on the animation.

Comment: So there is not special slider panel that does this out of the box for Universal Windows apps? It doesn't HAVE to be the RowDefinition solution. I was just wondering if there was another way. If there is none, I will proceed with what Chris suggested.

Comment: Nah nothing built in that I know of, but it's really easy to make one you can use globally if you like, just let us know if you run into any issues. Oh and a tip, you need @theirname at the beginning of a comment if you want people to be notified of your responses.