# Animating rectangle to move into window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I am wanting to animated a curved rectangle that I have to move INTO the actual Window component from outside of it, and preferably as if it just came on screen. So far, I have seen suggestions for scrolling animations INSIDE a canvas that lies INSIDE a window. I don't know if I can really get a Canvas to be outside the actual Window. Should I? Are there better ideas out there?

Here's my XAML and it's code-behind so far.

UserMenu.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ChatClient.UserMenu"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="UserMenu" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="media/favicon.gif" Background="#FF3C3636" Foreground="{x:Null}">
    <Window.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6D95" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.BorderBrush>
    <Grid x:Name="GridBody">
        <Canvas Name="WindowMainCanvas">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Menu" Fill="#755E5E83" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" RadiusY="27.5" RadiusX="27.5" Canvas.Left="545" Canvas.Top="23"/>
            <Button x:Name="ChatClientOnlyButton" Content="Chat (Clients Only)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="132,65,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource OTonButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#FF1C045B" Click="chatClientsOnlyOption" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="231,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="20" Visibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0A1D5F" Offset="0.374"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF6E7FB9" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
            <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="errorCanvas" Width="446" Height="17" Margin="36,152,35,151">
                <Rectangle x:Name="errorMarquee" Fill="#FF0A0A0C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Stroke="#FF5B1D1D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" Canvas.Left="-1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="errorText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="690" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF7E0202" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserMenu.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChatClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserMenu.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserMenu : Window
    {
        public UserMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleAnimation menuSlideInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            menuSlideInAnimation.From = Menu.Margin.Left;
            menuSlideInAnimation.To = 35;

            menuSlideInAnimation.Completed += (s, doneEvent) =>
            {
                //consider additional triggers
            };
            menuSlideInAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7.0));
            errorText.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.MarginProperty, menuSlideInAnimation, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
        }

        private void chatClientsOnlyOption(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not available just yet!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whoa, yea let me save you some of that overkill amigo. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145) answer is for Silverlight, but it's basically the same thing in this instance. Though you might change the X for Y if you want horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: Sweet! I was just making some similar code with Blend. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help a fellow KC'er

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of complex to do, but you could do this by.

1. Wrapping your rectangle you want to animate in a border control, and
   rendering it's contents to image.
2. Creating a transparent popup with a boundary outside your window
3. Animating the image of your rectangle within the popup
4. Closing the popup when the animation is done.

Here is a class that accepts a border control to animate:

```
public class SlideInPopup
{
    private Popup _popup;

    public SlideInPopup()
    {

    }

    public void SlideIn(Window parent, int heightOffset, Border animateControl, Duration duration)
    {
        if ((animateControl != null) && (parent != null))
        {
            int controlHeight = (int)animateControl.ActualHeight;
            int controlWidth = (int)animateControl.ActualWidth;                

            _popup = new Popup();

            double height = parent.Height;
            double widthOffset = parent.Width;
            double width = parent.Width * 2;

            var fromMargin = new Thickness(animateControl.Margin.Left + widthOffset, 
                                                animateControl.Margin.Top, 
                                                animateControl.Margin.Right, 
                                                animateControl.Margin.Bottom);

            var toMargin = animateControl.Margin;


            Image animateImage = new Image();     
            animateImage.Name = "imgAnimate";
            animateImage.Margin = fromMargin;
            animateImage.Height = controlHeight;
            animateImage.Width = controlWidth;
            animateImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            animateImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            animateImage.Source = CaptureScreen(animateControl, controlWidth, controlHeight);

            animateControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            animateControl.Height = 0;

            Grid child = new Grid();
            child.Height = height;
            child.Width = width;
            child.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            child.Children.Add(animateImage);

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation(fromMargin, toMargin, duration);
            animation.AccelerationRatio = 0.8;

            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

            storyboard.Completed += (s, doneEvent) =>
            {
                _popup.IsOpen = false;
                animateControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                animateControl.Height = controlHeight;
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, animateImage);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Margin)"));

            _popup.Height = height;
            _popup.Width = width;
            _popup.HorizontalOffset = parent.Left;
            _popup.VerticalOffset = parent.Top + heightOffset;
            _popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
            _popup.Child = child;
            _popup.IsOpen = true;

            child.Resources.Add("sbSlideIn", storyboard);

            storyboard.Begin();
        }            
    }

    private static BitmapSource CaptureScreen(Visual target, double dpiX, double dpiY)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(bounds.Width * dpiX / 96.0),
                                                        (int)(bounds.Height * dpiY / 96.0),
                                                        dpiX,
                                                        dpiY,
                                                        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(target);
            ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
        }
        rtb.Render(dv);
        return rtb;
    }
}
```

Then in your main window xaml you can wrap your rectangle with a border control and also remove the canvas positioning properties

```
<Border x:Name="borderRect" Margin="35,23,0,0">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Menu" Fill="#755E5E83" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" RadiusY="27.5" RadiusX="27.5"/ >
</Border>
```

You can then start the animation with this code:

```
var slideInPopup = new SlideInPopup();
int heightOffset = (int)this.Height - (int)((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualHeight;
slideInPopup.SlideIn(this, heightOffset, borderRect, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)));
```

Comment: Phew! While I do appreciate this answer, it is quite complex. Thanks though. I think I'll go with the first suggestion.