# UserControl animation Cannot resolve TargetName

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, win-universal-app

I'm trying to create a simple animation in a UWP user control, but I'm running into the error **Cannot Resolve TargetName**. The code is really simple and I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but I can't figure it out.

### XAML

```
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="ManipulationMediaViewerControl"
    ...
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ZoomAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewboxHost" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewboxHost" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox x:Name="ViewboxHost"
                 ManipulationMode="All"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=ManipulationMediaViewerControl, Path=ActualWidth}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=ManipulationMediaViewerControl, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### Code

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace ManipulationMediaViewer
{
    public sealed partial class ManipulationMediaViewer : UserControl
    {
        public ManipulationMediaViewer()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ZoomToFactor()
        {
            ZoomAnimation.Begin(); // Breaks here
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is when I try to start `ZoomAninmation.Begin();`, I get the exception:

> WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetName ViewboxHost. Additional
>   information: No installed components were detected.

I have this code in a very similar situation in different project that seems to work fine (it is outside of a user control). When this didn't work I deleted the code and created the storyboard through the Blend UI, but it resulted in the same code. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Move `x:Name="ViewboxHost"` to `<CompositeTransform x:Name="ViewboxHost" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />`

Comment: I believe you need to reference the control itself, not a component of the control as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab137711-f7ae-41eb-8541-3beeea3e6123/storyboard-to-animate-usercontrol-throws-exception-cannot-resolve-targetname?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: Oh that's definitely not correct, I do it all the [time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145), but I also have a bad habit of speeding through questions not paying enough attention. I'll swing back and actually peak in a minute, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok cool. I'm looking into it and I'm not sure if it's related, but it seems like the ContentPresenter ignores the RenderTransform of the ViewBox. That may be another question though

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your code ? I've tested your code on my side and cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've found the answer today. I was being stupid and setting the content of the control elsewhere, which ended up overwriting all components to my control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2017. I ended up compiling the usercontrol in its own uwp dll and adding it to my new project as reference. The issue went away after dowing that.