# Xaml Grid Visibility Transitions

Tags: xaml, grid, win-universal-app

Since I cannot find any official documentation about it I need to ask this questions. Is there any way to animate grids on visibility change?

I have tried adding `TransitionCollection`s to grids but it works only the first time that grid initialized.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition) answer but it also wont work because `Grid.Loaded` event fires even if grid is collapsed.

Comment: They haven't let me put win10 on my work machine yet so I won't be able to make you a UWP example at the moment, but are you familiar with `DataTriggerBehavior` and `ControlStoryboardAction`? You can tie to the Visibility and fire off the storyboard(s) that way instead of using Loaded event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event Loaded(). Just add attributes in XAML

```
 x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" Visibility="Collapsed"
```

and element will be completely collapsed.
To load it use somewhere in C# code standart:

```
SomeHiddenElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: It returns NullReferenceException when trying to set Visibility of the element. The ElementName returns null.

Comment: Well I realized element with `this.FindName`. Not the same thing happens I need to derealize the element.

Comment: You can use FindName only after you set element visibility (only after this it would be loaded)