# How do I create a VisualTransition translate storyboard that transitions from the *current* x value to a fixed final value?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

A user drags the item to the right of the screen, and while they do so, I change the MainGrid's translate X to track the finger. Once they let go of the finger, the storyboard completes the drag by animating MainGrid's translate X to the final value.

Basically I would like to say "CURRENT!" as per below, but this is not valid xaml. Search msdn docs or the internet didn't help. Must be something simple, right?

```
                <VisualTransition To="Dismissed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="CURRENT!" />
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 1" KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="385" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
```

Comment: Not visualizing what you're after exactly, got some sort of an example? Do you just want to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817854/xaml-grid-visibility-transition/22819145#22819145)?

Comment: @swinefeaster you are looking to bind to something, but this can create issues due to freezing.  I bound to the current value of width in this answer but it was tricky.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37708885/73804

Comment: updated question to clarify